# How to remove checkboxes after matching values using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have 4 checkboxes if I select 1 check box then I will get 1 or more sub values and if I select 2nd check box then I will get 1 or more sub values Here My Problem is If I uncheck the 1st check box then I have to remove unchecked check box values not with second check box values().

```js
$('.search-box1').on("click", function(e) {

  var inputVal1 = $(this).val();
  var cars = ["Saab", " Volvo", " BMW", " ABC", " HONDA", " TVS"];
  $(".arrVal").html(cars);

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row">
  <div>
    <label>First Page</label>
    <input type="checkbox" name="txtCheck" id="txtCheck" class="search-box1" value="First Page">
  </div>

  <div>
    <label>Second Page</label>
    <input type="checkbox" name="txtCheck" id="txtCheck" class="search-box1" value="Second Page">
  </div>

  <div>
    <label>Third Page</label>
    <input type="checkbox" name="txtCheck" id="txtCheck" class="search-box1" value="Third Page">
  </div>

  <div>
    <label>Fourth Page</label>
    <input type="checkbox" name="txtCheck" id="txtCheck" class="search-box1" value="Fourth Page">
  </div>
</div>

<div class="arrVal"></div>
```

Comment: Can you please explain more or give examples of what you are trying to achieve. And also post your existing js code.

Comment: bro how to put js separately? Also put jQuery plugin 2.20

Comment: Edited. What are you trying to achieve exactly? You want to show the value of selected checkboxes on `#arrVal` ? :)

Comment: For Example First Checkbox associated with array values "Saab", "Volvo", "BMW" and second check box associated with  "ABC", "HONDA", "TVS" If I select First Check box I will Get  "Saab", "Volvo", "BMW" and If Select Second Check box I will Get "ABC", "HONDA", "TVS" along with First checkbox values... Now My problem is If I uncheck second check box I should preserve first check box values but that is happening.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- You can construct your cars variable as object. Using the checkbox
  value as key.
- Use `change` as event
- Use `$('.search-box1:checked')` selector to get all checked `.search-box1` and use `map` to loop thru the objects.
- Use `join()` to make the array into a string(comma seperated).

```js
$('.search-box1').on("change", function(e) {

  var inputVal1 = $(this).val();
  var cars = {
    value1: ["Saab", "Volvo", "BMW"],
    value2: ["ABC", "HONDA", "TVS"],
    value3: [],
    value4: [],
    value5: [],
  }

  var result = $('.search-box1:checked').map(function() {
    return cars[this.value] || [];
  }).get();

  $(".arrVal").html(result.join());

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row">
  <div>
    <label>First Page</label>
    <input type="checkbox" name="txtCheck" id="txtCheck" class="search-box1" value="value1">
  </div>

  <div>
    <label>Second Page</label>
    <input type="checkbox" name="txtCheck" id="txtCheck" class="search-box1" value="value2">
  </div>

  <div>
    <label>Third Page</label>
    <input type="checkbox" name="txtCheck" id="txtCheck" class="search-box1" value="value3">
  </div>

  <div>
    <label>Fourth Page</label>
    <input type="checkbox" name="txtCheck" id="txtCheck" class="search-box1" value="value4">
  </div>
</div>

<div class="arrVal"></div>
```

Comment: In this I am getting Live data from database that means dynamic values.

Comment: Thats so broad. You have to give details. :)